# Spring MVC - can I "bind" ModelMap to view?

Tags: java, spring, view, binding, model

I have this piece of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/authUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String authUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
                        @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model){
(...)
if (password.equals(user.getPassword())){
            ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
            modelMap.put("loggedUser", user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
            return "home";
        }
        else{
            model.put("info", "Bad data!");
            return "index";
        }
```

For bad password, everything is correct - it returns a with information "bad data", but if password is correct I can't get an info about logged user (but it redirects correctly). Because ModelMap model is ,,bind" to index.jsp it works when it redirects to index jsp, but is there a way to "bind" new ModelMap to view called home.jsp with simply way or I have to use ModelAndView?
Thank you in advance.

**@SOLVED**: It was my stupidity, I simple do not initialize name and surname in variable user, and because of it there were a "" instead name and surname which I want to see in home.jsp. Now, with user with name and surname set it works great :)

Comment: Why you crate new ModelMap? Just use the one passed as argument, like in the else section.

Comment: @Evgeni if I do this:
 
model.put("user", user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
return "home"; I cannot see anything in <h1 id="helloUser">
             ${user}
        </h1> in home jsp, that's why I think ModelMap model is ,,bind" to index.jsp - with index jsp it works correctly - I see information in <h1>${info}</h1> (request comes from index.jsp)

Comment: @Evgeni You were right, It works very well - I simply not initialize fields name and surname in user class and because of it there were empty strings. Thank you for help because you showed my right way to solve this problem :)